# Environment variable in .subversion servers on Linux

Tags: svn, syntax, environment-variables, mount, lxc

I mount my .subversion folder in my LXC container, but since I use a different username there, some configurations do not work.

I want to use an environment variable to set the path to my cert file.
Currently I use `/home/max/` on my host

```
ssl-client-cert-file = /home/max/version/cert.p12
```

but I want to use something like `${HOME}` to have a working configuration for my LXC container and host as well, but this syntax does not work.

Any ideas like the syntax must be?

Answer (score 1):

You can set environment variables with [`lxc config`](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/doc/containers.md#keyvalue-configuration):

So: `lxc config set ct1 environment.HOME /home/max`

Then in the `ct1` container `$HOME` would be `/home/max`